# Touch .env Won't Work, Touch anything.js Does

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

The Title pretty much sums this issue up, I am trying to create an .env file on my deployed EC2 instance by running `touch .env` in the CLI for the deployment. The command returns no errors, indicating it created the file, but I cannot `cd` into it, and it does not appear when I run `ls`.
It works totally fine if I try anything that isn't an .env file, so what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`touch` is for creating an empty file, or updating the access and modification times of an existing file.

`cd` is for changing to a directory. Don't try to `cd` into a file, because that is never going to work.

`ls` without `-a` does not show any files that start with a `.` character.

Try `ls -a` to see if the `.env` file exists.